# Можно ли исправить предложение знаками, не сокращая?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

> Но что же Флоренция? Ну, во-первых, это знаменитый флорентийский
>   стейк. Тем, кто не привык к поглощению сырого мяса, чуть тронутый
>   огнём огромный кусок – от полкило и больше, и к которому не положено
>   подавать даже соли (ибо считается, что приправа есть попытка укрыть
>   *вторую свежесть*), вряд ли покажется чем-то замечательным, этаким кулинарным шедевром.

Что делать с:

*от полкило и больше, и к которому*?

Comment: Здесь явно лишнее " и"; "этакий" плохо сочетается с отрицанием (-> такой уж). _Тем, кто не привык к поглощению сырого мяса, чуть тронутый огнём огромный кусок (от полкило и больше), к которому не положено подавать даже соли (считается, что приправа есть попытка облагородить "вторую свежесть"), вряд ли покажется чем-то замечательным, таким уж кулинарным шедевром._ Можно избавиться от двух запутывающих препинаний, начав с "Непривычным к поглощению сырого мяса чуть..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь важно, выделяя при помощи тире пояснение к размеру куска (к слову *огромный*), не потерять связь придаточного предложения с существительным *кусок*. Поэтому я предлагаю разделить эти две части следующим образом:

«Но что же Флоренция? Ну, во-первых, это знаменитый флорентийский стейк. Тем, кто не привык к поглощению сырого мяса, чуть тронутый огнём **огромный — от полкило и больше — кусок, к которому** не положено подавать даже соли (ибо считается, что приправа есть попытка укрыть вторую свежесть), вряд ли покажется чем-то замечательным, этаким кулинарным шедевром».

Кстати, фразу «от полкило и больше» я считаю тавтологией, потому что предлог *от* уже подразумевает нижнюю границу, то есть означает «не меньше 0,5 кг».

Comment: Сделаем: ***с полкило***! )))

Answer (score 2):

Но что же Флоренция? Ну, во-первых, это знаменитый флорентийский стейк. Тому, кто не привык к поглощению сырого мяса, чуть тронутый огнём огромный кусок **– от полкило и больше, к которому не положено подавать даже соли (ибо считается, что приправа есть попытка укрыть вторую свежесть),** —  вряд ли покажется чем-то замечательным, этаким кулинарным шедевром.

Comment: А где закрывается запятая, открывшаяся перед "к которому"? Тогда после скобки - зап-тире?

Comment: Да, запятую придется поставить. Розенталь: 3) перед вторым тире ставится запятая, если этого требует структура второй части основного предложения или ВСТАВНОЙ КОНСТРУКЦИИ: Пример у Лопатина: Валерия — так звали девушку, от тоски по которой я сбежал из деревни в Москву, — слушала меня, мечтательно глядела перед собой (Сол.);

Comment: Не следует ли "вторую свежесть" писать в кавычках? И не укрыть, а скрыть (замаскировать, затушевать)?

Comment: 1) Скрыть - более точное выражение, если только автор не использует "укрыть" в особом (ироническом, например)  смысле.  2) "Вторая свежесть" стала фразеологизмом, например: Для продуктов, маркированных сроком годности, никакая вторая свежесть не допускается. Поэтому кавычки на усмотрение автора, но в принципе можно поставить, так сочетание даже заметнее будет.

Answer (score 1):

Я увидела так:

Но что же Флоренция? Ну, во-первых, это знаменитый флорентийский стейк. **Тем, кто не привык к поглощению сырого мяса, чуть тронутого огнём — кусок огромный, от полкило и больше, к нему не положено подавать даже соли (ибо считается, что приправа есть попытка укрыть вторую свежесть), — стейк вряд ли покажется чем-то замечательным, этаким кулинарным шедевром.**